# RubyMine syntax error - new version of ruby 2.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error, rubymine

I have recently updated my ruby version. I had ruby 2.1.0p0 and now moved to ruby 2.1.2p95.

The problem is that now almost all my files have syntax error showing in rubymine.

This used to be fine:

```
format.json { render json: data }
```

Now I have to change it to this to remove the error syntax:

```
format.json { render json => data }
```

The probleme is that I have more than 2000 files, I cannot changed all of them will take me ages.

Please help.

Comment: That sounds more like a problem you would have if you had downgraded to ruby 1.8.x. Ruby 2.1 hasn't changed hash syntax.

Comment: What is your SDK set to in RubyMine's Preferences -> Project Settings -> Ruby SDK and Gems dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this question and I'm pretty sure I have your answer, though I would need more information to be certain. (The same information Dave Schweisguth asked for)

90% likely you need to set your "Ruby SDK and Gems" setting to the appropriate Ruby version, add that recent update to 2.1.2p95 to your list and choose it, as described at http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/quickstart/#Step_3_Manage_Gems

Good luck.